# Jquery Loading news listings into dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want simply to load/display my top 500 news into my DOM.
I'm not sure why doesn't display it on my  `<div id="hackernewsrss" ></div>`

And if there's any other better way to display this? or to code it? Perhaps I can learn.

```js
var LoadNews = $("#hackernewsrss");


LoadNews.load(function(event) {
  parseTopStories('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories', '#hackernewsrss');
});


function parseTopStories(url, container) {
  var hackernewsAPI = "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json";
  $.getJSON(hackernewsAPI, function(json) {
    var requests = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      requests.push($.getJSON('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/' + json[i] + '.json'));
    }
    $.when.apply($, requests)
      .done(function() {
        var results = []
          .slice.call(arguments);
        var list = results.map(function(arr) {
          var thetemplate = '<li><a href="' + arr[0].url + '">' + arr[0].title + '</a></li>';
          return thetemplate;
        });
        $(container).html('<ol>' + list.join('') + '</ol>');
        console.log(container); //logs #hackernewsrss
      });
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hackernewsrss"></div>
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Have you checked your console for any errors reported there?

Comment: @Jeremy no, I'll try now

Comment: Checking the error console is *always* the first step of debugging.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher agree but looks like doesn't load also into the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try:

```
$(function(){
      parseTopStories('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories', '#hackernewsrss');
});
```

All goes well.

I am not sure why you have load event attached to the div. It is usually used to trigger when image is loaded or window:
[JQuery reference](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

Comment: No worries, we all do those.

Comment: Also, https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json returns 446 values right now, not 500 and it won't work with 500. You may want to count how many it returns and put that number in your loop instead of 10 or 500.